# I can't seem to understand this

Tags: javascript, html

```js
# MCVE document stub
var document = []
document.title = "TEST"
# end stub

# code to test
var mainPage = [
  "Home",
  "About Us",
  "Javascript Playground",
  "News",
  "TEST"
];

for (i = 0; i < mainPage.length; i++) {
  if (document.title === mainPage[i]) {
    console.log("We ARE here!: " + mainPage[i]);
  } else {
    console.log("We are not Here: " + mainPage[i]);
  }
  enter code here
}
```

My HTML title is TEST. So the code works, but I don't understand,
how come *that [i]* lists me the array elements? isn't `i` a number ?
How does it read me inside the array (mainPage)?

Comment: Does your code actually work with the `enter code here` part ? As answers indicate, I strongly suggest you read some programming book / online training to be acquainted with the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are a **set of values**

`["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]` is an **array**.

Each value has an **associated index**. Index's start at 0.

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
Indexes:      0    1    2    3    4
```

As you can see, the value `"c"` is **associated** with the index of `2`

To get that element, you would use **brackets**. First, you have the name of the variable (`array`), and then you have the **brackets** with the **index inside**.

```
array[0] //The result is "a"
array[2] //The result is "c"
array[4] //The result is "e"
```

In your case, `i` starts off at 0, and since i is 0, `mainPage[i]` is the same as `mainPage[0]`. Using the index's I above, you would notice that `mainPage[0]` is `"Home"`

You can find out more about Arrays [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i` are a count and she are controlled by lenght of array.

Then after each execution of for, the value of `i` are change.

You need understand logic programmer basic, for statement, arrays and after you need learn JavaScript.

[For statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) (JavaScript)
[Introduction JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials)